# Optional chaining operator in Visual Studio Code

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use optional chaining operator (`?`) in TypeScript 4.1.2.

```
handleError(err: any) {
    let message = err.error?.message;
}
```

It doesn't give any compilations error however visual studio code shows "Expression expected" error.

[image: VS Code Error]

How can I fix this?

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "~4.1.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that VS Code is using the project's version of TypeScript installed in `node_modules`.

From the [documentation on TypeScript in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling#_using-newer-typescript-versions):

> The active TypeScript version and its install location are displayed in the Status Bar when viewing a TypeScript file:
>
> [image: TypeScript status bar version]
>
> #### Using the workspace version of TypeScript
>
> If your workspace has a specific TypeScript version, you can switch between the workspace version of TypeScript and the version that VS Code uses by default by opening a TypeScript or JavaScript file and clicking on the TypeScript version number in the Status Bar. A message box will appear asking you which version of TypeScript VS Code should use:
>
> [image: TypeScript version selector]
>
> Use this to switch between the version of TypeScript that comes with VS Code and the version of TypeScript in your workspace. You can also trigger the TypeScript version selector with the **TypeScript: Select TypeScript Version** command.